# Single piece of content, multiple URLs?

Tags: wagtail

I have a use case that I could use some advice on.

We publish multiple products, each of which has it's own subtree on the site. Generally, a piece of content gets published to just a single product, e.g. a news article gets published to product A and can be accessed at one URL.

However, sometimes we have content that we want to publish to multiple products, e.g. a single news article gets published to products A, B, and C and will be available at 3 different URLs.

With our current CMS we end up doing this by copying and pasting the content, which is a hassle for editors, especially if the content needs to be updated.

An ideal scenario would be where and editor edits the content in one place, specifies the products to publish to, and the content is served by more than one URL and with a template that is product-specific.

It seems that `RoutablePageMixin` could be useful here, but I'm not sure how to handle letting the editor specify the destination products and making the routing aware of that choice.

Has anyone solved a similar problem using Wagtail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than thinking of your news articles as being child objects of one or more products, it might help to think of them as one big pool of news articles which are categorised by product. Your product page will then effectively be a filtered index page of news articles.

Here's how I'd model it:

- If you want your news articles to exist at a canonical URL that's independent of any particular category, or you want to make use of page moderation and/or previewing, then define NewsArticle as a page model; otherwise, define it as a snippet or a [ModelAdmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html)-managed model.
- On the NewsArticle model, have an InlinePanel where editors can associate as many related products as required:

  ```
  class NewsArticle(Page):
      body = RichTextField()
      date = models.DateField()

      content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
          FieldPanel('body'),
          FieldPanel('date'),
          InlinePanel('related_products', label="Related products"),
      ]

  class NewsArticleRelatedProduct(Orderable):
      news_article = ParentalKey(NewsArticle, related_name='related_products')
      product = models.ForeignKey(ProductPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='news_articles')

      panels = [
          PageChooserPanel('product'),
      ]
  ```
- On your ProductPage model, add a method that returns a queryset of news items, filtered and sorted appropriately:

  ```
  class ProductPage(Page):
      # ...
      def get_news_articles(self):
          return self.news_articles.live().order_by('-date')
  ```

You can then loop over the news articles in your product page template, using a tag like `{% for news_article in page.get_news_articles %}`.

Comment: I like that idea of inversion, gives me some ideas to think on. Thanks for the mind-shift!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem in Wagtail, the `RoutablePageMixin` is the key to solving this problem.

If you have /blog/A/slug-product/, /blog/B/slug-product/, /blog/C/slug-product/ , then you can get the slug value `slug-product` here, then use this value to search the distinct content in your db.

```
class BlogPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    def get_posts(self):
        return PostPage.objects.descendant_of(self).live()
    @route(r'^(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(.+)/$')
    def post_by_date_slug(self, request, year, month, day, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        post_page = self.get_posts().filter(slug=slug).first()
        return Page.serve(post_page, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, I did not use the date info of the url but the slug value to get the blog post object, you can follow the pattern here to use regex to match the url you want.

If the slug values in urls are also different, this solution might not work very well, but in most cases, this solution can work fine.

I have written a blog post talking about how to use RoutablePageMixin to make the page routable, you can check this link if you wang to get more about RoutablePageMixin.

[Routable Page](https://blog.michaelyin.info/2017/06/30/wagtail-tutorials-routable-page/)

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)